# Error: Unexpected '!'. Escaping special characters with \ may help. - Preact build failing with no location

Tags: javascript, babeljs, preact, preact-cli

## Error: Unexpected '!'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.  - Preact build failing with no location

[image: errorcode]

Preact production build is failing without giving any error location after `additional chunk assets processing`

*Going after all '!' manually seems to be the only way I can think of right now!*

nvm 12.18.3 
ubuntu 20.04

```js
npm run build

> cdms-app@0.0.1 build /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app
> preact build --no-prerender --dest public --esm --analyze --verbose

⚠ WARN Could not find sw.js in /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/src. Using the default service worker.
⚠ WARN /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/prerender-urls.json doesn't exist, using default!
Uh oh AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Unable to find a place to inject the manifest. Please ensure that your service worker file contains the following:/(\.precacheAndRoute\()\s*\[\s*\]\s*(\)|,)/
   at Object._callee$ (/home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/workbox-build/build/entry-points/inject-manifest.js:82:13)
   at tryCatch (/home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
   at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
   at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (/home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
   at step (/home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
   at /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13 {
 generatedMessage: false,
 code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
 actual: null,
 expected: true,
 operator: '=='
}
Build  [=     ] 10% (1.4s) buildingNodent: Warning - noNodentExtensions option requires acorn >=v4.x. Extensions installed.
Build  [=     ] 12% (7.4s) building[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/src/components/createvisitmodal/index.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Build  [=   ] 15% (171.5s) building[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/src/routes/siloAdministration/index.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Build  [=   ] 15% (271.8s) building[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/src/routes/caseDetail/index.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Build  [=   ] 17% (289.7s) building[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Build  [==  ] 40% (289.8s) building[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Build  [==  ] 40% (377.0s) building[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/src/components/semiDetailView/index.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Build  [====] 90% (487.8s) additional chunk assets processing[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/src/components/createvisitmodal/index.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/src/routes/siloAdministration/index.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/src/routes/caseDetail/index.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /home/technative/Documents/Projects/CrystalDevDocker/cdms-app/src/components/semiDetailView/index.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.


Build failed! 

Error: Unexpected '!'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
```

Comment: Do you have a ! inside a content block in your CSS?

Comment: Do you have a repo I can clone? Alternatively, our error handling might be less than ideal for this case. You can go into `node_modules/preact-cli` and add a `console.log(info)` [after this line](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/blob/6aba5d8e4c165c81f258ca9f367fea6c9a08cf17/packages/cli/lib/lib/webpack/run-webpack.js#L161). That might show a better error, or might not. Depends on where it's coming from.

Answer (score -1):

*Going after all '!' manually seems to be the only way I can think of right now!*

Comment: So manually going for it was the only way. The issue was in Style folder, If you are facing same issue comment your css/styl files and check if your build is going forward without it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).